# What may cause my error during Manjaro installation?

Tags: linux, boot, system-installation, manjaro

I've been trying to install Linux Manjaro for a few days, but when I try to enter the installer, I'm left with: **Started TLP system startup/shutdown** and **Started Accounts Service**, and it does not start.

I have tried all this:

- pci = noaer
- pci = nomsi
- nomodeset
- start with free and noonfree drivers
- create the USB with Rufus in ISO and dd mode
- create the USB with: win32 writer, Rufus (Windows), isousb and the terminal in (Linux)
- start with a DVD

But nothing serves; it always stops in this part.

Does anyone know why this error occurs?

[image: pci errores are fixed with pci=noaer]

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. The only solution was to install the Manjaro architect ISO. It's a long installation but it worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/220091)

Comment: @Archemar why not? It looks like Jakob is suggesting that the OP install from a different ISO. Yes, it would benefit from a bit more detail, but if that solves it, this seems like an answer.

Comment: A quick read made it sound like Jakob was adding that he too has this problem. I resolved the confusion by changing the verb in the first sentence from present tense to past.